# Searching method in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building an asp.net core searching API which should return a list of videos who has the same searched QR code(the QR code is a ForeignKey)
This is the video model:

```cs
public class Video
{
    [Key]
    public int VideoId { get; set; }
    public string Exercice { get; set; }
    public string Titre { get; set; }
    public int Sexe { get; set; }
    public int Categorie { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpload { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [ForeignKey("Machine")]
    public string Machine_Qr { get; set; }

    public Machine machine { get; set; }
    public Coache Coache { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the search controller:

```cs
[HttpGet("{Qr}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Video>> Search(string qr)
{
     IEnumerable<Video> query = _context.videos.Where(e => e.Machine_Qr == qr);
     if ((query != null))
            return query;
     else
            return Enumerable.Empty<Video>().ToList();
 }
```

but I tested it and I got an empty list every time.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** your edit fixed the first logic issue in the original question. But the query also needs to have an `await` since the function is an `async Task`.

Since your function returns an `IEnumerable`, you shouldn't need to call `.ToList()` ... try this:

```
[HttpGet("{Qr}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Video>> Search(string qr)
{
     return await _context.videos.Where(e => e.Machine_Qr == qr) ?? Enumerable.Empty<Video>()
 }
```

Comment: a shorter version could be `return _context.videos.Where(e => e.Machine_Qr == qr) ?? Enumerable.Empty<Video>()`

Comment: @Mario I used the two method and I got the same empty list, he allways considered the querry as not null

Comment: @Mario can it be because of the qr code is a ForeignKey?